# ROS Answers SE migration: opencv ubuntu

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly my englısh is not good but ı will try say. ı am researching ubuntu and opencv. Which ubuntu's version is better for opencv?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66535/opencv-ubuntu/) by [agp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5310/agp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Doesn't matter very much, a recent one will probably support more camera's. For your ROS you can pick for instance Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise). See the opencv site for more info..

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1